# Handling differents parameters in the same form with the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Let's say that I have a `Problem` and `Restriction` model class. Problem has many restrictions and accepts nested attributes for restrictions.
The Restriction model represents a mathematical expression like:

- X < 1
- 1 <= X <= 2
- 2 < X

When I create a `Problem` through a form I must also create the restrictions (always 3).

For the restriction form I fill the numbers. i.e: `X <  [Input a number]`
Note that the second restriction need two fields to be fill but the first and third need just one.
How can I create each restriction in Problem controller with differents params?
For the first and third restriction just I need pass a number but with the second I need pass two numbers (maybe and Array with the two numbers)

Please, let me know if I'm not clear.

Comment: Impossible to tell without your schema for `Restriction`.

Comment: I will try at this moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the name of the inputs with a empty array:

```
number_field_tag 'problem[restrictions][1][]', 0
number_field_tag 'problem[restrictions][1][]', 5
```

And then in your ProblemController you should receive params like this:

```
params[:problem][:restrictions][1]
# => contains the 2 values serialized as array
```

So the full form would be:

```
X < 
<%= number_field_tag 'problem[restrictions][0]', 0 %>

<%= number_field_tag 'problem[restrictions][1][]', 0 %>
<= X <=
<%= number_field_tag 'problem[restrictions][1][]', 5 %>

<%= number_field_tag 'problem[restrictions][2]', 0 %>
< X
```

And you will end up with the following params:

```
params = {
  problem: { #all the Problem attributes filled in the form },
  restrictions: 
  [
    <value of first input>,
    [<value of second input>, <value of third input>],
    <value of fourth input>
  ]
}
```